# I am trying to run code in Numpy arrays .. But an attribute error keeps coming up

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, attributes

[image]

See my image .. the code is simple .. yet it is generating error(just to fill space)

Comment: Add code as text instead of screenshots

Comment: arr_0 is an integer, so doesn't have an ndim. Also, please don't post code as an image. Try `type(arr_0)` to verify this and then look at the code where arr_0 is defined for clues - if you don't show where arr_0 is created, then you're only giving us half your problem

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. And do NOT post images of code.

Answer (score 0):

By the error code arr_0 is an int. try `type(arr_0)` for verify.